# How do I setup the Spyder/JupyterLab environment so I can run QGIS programs from there?

Tags: spyder, environment, qgis

I enjoy using Spyder and JupyterLab to develop code. Now I want to develop code for use in QGIS and find that the environment setup has me stumped. I want to develop code in Spyder that will run QGIS tools within Spyder. To do that I need a way to setup access to the QGIS libraries from Spyder. I have tried the other way around....so far have not found a way.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

1. I installed QGIS in my Program Files directory using the QGIS installer.
2. I installed the whole of the Anaconda distribution in my user Appdata directories per the default locations
3. I then tried to set variables within Spyder to "see QGIS" and
4. Failed to find qgis commands and libraries

Next attempt

1. Created a new environment within Navigator called 'qgis_env'. Activated it.
2. Opened command prompt and installed the qgis environment. Activated that.
3. Opened new command prompt from the qgis environment(just to be sure) and started qgis from there. So far so good. Selected an active Layer in the interface for QGIS
4. tried the following:

   1. imported qgis.core
   2. ran vlayer = iface.activeLayer
   3. This failed with a "NameError: name 'iface' is not defined'

Next attempt:
1) Same as above but got the env path inside QGIS using a sys command and set that up in the qgis_env...failed

All I want to achieve is to have both running simultaneously so I can edit in Anaconda and interact with the active QGIS environment to get libs and layer info.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe how you have tried installing the QGIS libraries and how you start Spyder.